# Multiple html video elements iOS issue

Tags: javascript, html, ios, video

I'm currently working on this web app:
https://nowe.menu/nowe-menu

The problem is that videos work's perfectly normal on all devices except the iOS.
iOS tend to not show every single one - some of them a just not displayed.

I was trying alread to use some lazyload javascript libraries for videos - but it doesn't work either.

Do you guys have some ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to this.

If you're lazy loading videos - you have to unload them if they are out of viewport.
It's strange but iphone got like an limited amount of movies that can be loaded at the same time.

I've tested it even with iPhone 6 and it works!

So here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {


 var lazyVideos = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("video.lazy"));
    const options = {
          rootMargin: "500px"
        };



 if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
  
var lazyVideoObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(function(video) {
    if (video.isIntersecting) {
      for (var source in video.target.children) {
        var videoSource = video.target.children[source];
        if (typeof videoSource.tagName === "string" && videoSource.tagName === "SOURCE") {
          videoSource.src = videoSource.dataset.src;
        }
      }

      video.target.load();
    } else {
        for (var source in video.target.children) {
            var videoSource = video.target.children[source];
            if (typeof videoSource.tagName === "string" && videoSource.tagName === "SOURCE") {
              videoSource.src = '';
            }
          }
          video.target.load();
    }
  });
}, options);

lazyVideos.forEach(function(lazyVideo) {
  lazyVideoObserver.observe(lazyVideo);
});
  }
});
```

As you can see i'm loading videos in the `if` statement (when they are visible), and unloading them in `else` statement (when they are not visible) and then they're loaded once again when they visible again.

Als in the options i've setted `rootmargin` to 500px - so loading it's only visible when you're fast scrolling.

That's how it works :) Now you can have million videos on one page.